# How can I use "\s+" as a seperator in polars?

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

So I have a large file of data that's can be up to 11 columns wide, it looks something like this.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

When I read in using pandas i used the code:
`pd.read_csv(file_dir, skiprows = 1, sep = '\s+')`.
When pandas reads it, it creates a dataframe that's 3x8(Which is correct).
Using Polars:
`pl.read_csv(file_dir, skip_rows=1, orient='col')`
When polars reads it, it creates a data frame that's 3x1.
I think its due to the separator, but I'm not sure. I tried using "\s+" in polars but it doesn't like it because its bigger than one byte. The delimiter in these files in 7 white spaces.

Comment: can you check how the data is stored? with an index or without index?

Comment: @hilo Its not stored using an index, its essentially just a large file with a bunch of numbers formatted like above

Comment: can you try without skipping the first row?

Comment: Sorry , i should have mentioned this, but the first row has the file name in it. I dont want it in the dataframe which is why i skip it

Comment: Try sep=' '. Let me know if this works

Comment: no it did not work

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`read_csv`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html#polars.read_csv) and [`scan_csv`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html#polars.scan_csv), the delimiter must be a single-byte character.  As such, you'll need to preprocess your file to convert the 7-whitespace delimiter to a single-byte delimiter before reading it with Polars.

The single-byte limitation is done for performance reasons.  For some further background, you can look at [this discussion](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/2728) on GitHub.  The discussion includes some suggestions for picking single-byte delimiters that are not likely to be found in your input file.